# Clean up if else control flow in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following simple number guess program

```
import System.Random

turn :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
turn number attempt attempts =
  do
    if attempts == 0
       then putStrLn "You lose"
       else if attempt==number
               then putStrLn "You got it!"
               else if attempt==0
                       then guess number attempt attempts
               else if attempt < number
                       then do
                            putStrLn "The number is greater"
                            guess number attempt attempts
               else
                      do
                        putStrLn "The number is lesser"
                        guess number attempt attempts

guess :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
guess number attempt attempts =
  do
    putStr "Try and guess number "
    g <- getLine
    let number' = read g :: Int
    let check = (number'==number)
    let attempts' = if check then attempts else attempts - 1
    turn number number' attempts'

numberGuess :: IO ()
numberGuess = do
  let attempts = 5
  number <- randomRIO (0, 10) :: IO Int
  turn number 0 attempts
```

How can I clean up the ugly if else or what techniques are available in haskell?

Comment: You might also have a look at `-XMultiWayIf` syntax extension. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#multi-way-if

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your outermost `do` in `turn` doesn't actually do anything. So you should nix it. Next, use pattern matching and guards to begin to clean things up.

```
turn _number _attempt 0 = putStrLn "You lose"
turn number attempt attempts
  | attempt == number = putStrLn "You got it!"
  | attempt == 0 = guess number attempt attempts
  | attempt < number = do
      putStrLn "The number is greater"
      guess number attempt attempts
  | otherwise = do
      putStrLn "The number is lesser"
      guess number attempt attempts
```

The final step to clean up `turn` will be factoring out the pattern "Do something, then call `guess`". I'll let you try that on your own. I used a pattern match for the first case to demonstrate that technique, which is very often the right one. In this *particular* case you might be better off just using guards.

For `guess`, the easy bit is just to combine some expressions.

```
guess :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
guess number attempt attempts = do
  putStr "Try and guess number "
  g <- getLine
  let attempts' = if read g == number
                  then attempts
                  else attempts - 1
  turn number number' attempts'
```

Note, however, that `read` generally shouldn't be used to process user input, as it will crash your program on bad input. Import `Text.Read` and use `readMaybe`, perhaps.